# What is the relationship b/w mass’s effect on the curvature of space vs the expansion of space?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, curvature, cosmological-constant

As is well known, General relativity explains that mass and energy bend the curvature of spacetime. Mass energy of different amounts lead to different space time curvatures.

As is also well known, the mass density of the universe effected whether the universe expanded after the Big Bang or collapsed in on itself, and the rate of expansion in the absence of collapse.

My question is: what is the relationship between these two consequences of mass on the universe? Presumably expansion is independent of curvature? But why, if mass influences both curvature and expansion?

I am a physics novice, and so I’m not sure if I’ve got at the heart of my question here.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, matter and energy *gravitate* by causing *space-time* curvature. Matter and energy lead to the expansion of the Universe, which is a form of spacetime curvature.

In more detail, the size of the Universe can be described by the *scale factor* $a(t)$. We can choose a convention that $a=1$ today, then we can say that any length between two freely falling points in space measured to be a distance $L$ apart today will be measured to be $a(t)L$ at time $t$. The *expansion rate* $H(t)=\dot{a}/a$ tells us how quickly or slowly the Universe is expanding.

Let's say the energy of the Universe is $\rho$. The energy density represents "matter and energy." The *Friedmann equation* relates the energy density to the expansion rate
\begin{equation}
H^2 = \frac{8\pi G\rho}{3}
\end{equation}
where $G$ is Newton's constant.
This is the equation form of my statement "Matter and energy lead to the expansion of the Universe." It follows directly from Einstein's equations, and the assumption that on large scales the Universe is homogenous and isotropic (the [cosmological principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_principle)).

The expansion rate $H$ is directly related to the *spacetime curvature*. One relatively simple measure of the curvature is the *Ricci curvature scalar* $R$, which is zero when there is no spacetime curvature, and usually (though not always) nonzero when there is spacetime curvature. In an expanding Universe, the Ricci curvature is related to the expansion rate via
\begin{equation}
R = \frac{6}{c^2}\left(\dot{H} + 2 H^2\right) 
\end{equation}
This justifies my earlier statement "the expansion of the Universe... is a form of spacetime curvature."

In the above equations, for simplicity and because it is consistent with current observations, I've assumed there is no *spatial* curvature (note spatial curvature is different from space*time* curvature). The spatial curvature modifies both the Friedmann equation (hence spatial curvature contributes to the expansion rate), and to the equation for the Ricci scalar (hence spatial curvature modifies the spacetime curvature).

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your considered response. I have a couple of follow-up questions that are no doubt entirely naive based on popular science books. You say expansion is a form of spacetime curvature, but I am under the impression that we are probably living in a pretty-much flat universe that is expanding. If so, how can there be such an intimate link between expansion and curvature (ie. a non-flat spacetime)?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this: "Matter and energy lead to the expansion of the Universe"?

Comment: Indeed, Arpad raises another question: doesn’t matter (mass) *slow* the rate of expansion: i.e. dark matter ensures galaxies remain intact.

Comment: @David Our Universe's *spatial* curvature is flat. But the *space**time*** curvature is not. The expansion rate $H$ appears in the space**time** curvature, as shown above in the expression for the Ricci scalar $R$. It makes sense that expansion should be related to spacetime curvature, since it is a change of the spatial geometry with time.

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei It's all in the Friedmann equation that I wrote down, $H^2 \propto \rho$. If you have some energy density, $\rho$, then the expansion rate $H$ will be nonzero. This assumes you thinking about large enough scales (>100 Mpc) that we can approximate the Universe as being homogeneous and isotropic.

Comment: @David All I've said is that the expansion rate $H$ is non-zero if there is energy density $\rho$ present because of the Friedmann equation. Also the Friedmann equation only holds on very large scales >100 Mpc where we can approximate the Universe as homogeneous and isotropic. It's a more detailed (but answerable) question to ask whether different types of matter increase or decrease the expansion rate. Also the Friedman equation does not apply at the scale of individual galaxies. The distance between galaxies expands, not galaxies themselves.